# include.model.getTableName is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am using this snippet from the sequelize documentation

```
Project.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Task,
    where: { state: Sequelize.col('project.state') }
  }]
})
```

but it generates this error:

```
include.model.getTableName is not a function
```

someone who can help me with this

Comment: What is `Task`? if it doesn't have a method called `getTableName` then that could be why that error is being thrown

Comment: Provide full of your error.

Comment: matt Ellen  thanks for answering,

Task is a table that is associated with the Project table in this way:
Project.hasMany (models.Task),
Task.belongsTo (models.Project),
When I use the code to search among associated tables I get this error

Comment: hoangdv thanks for answering, this all the error the query